# JSON object in Jijna Template

Tags: python, json, jinja2

I have a little problem with display list of JSON Object in Jinja Template.

JSON list:

```
[
{"user_id": 1, "name": "Bartek Chaber"},
{"user_id": 2, "name": "Linus Torvalrds"},
{"user_id": 3, "name": "Alonzo Church"},
{"user_id": 4, "name": "Gerald Jay Sussman "}
]
```

Jijna Template:

```
   <ul>
    {% for i in content %}
        <li>{{ content[i]['name'] }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

I have no idea how to display the names of users in this template.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass parsed json object to template.

And in template:

```
<ul>
{% for person in content %}
    <li>{{ person['name'] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```